# Let $f(x)$ be non-negative, symmetric, monotone on $(-\infty,0)$. Show $f(x)=af(x-x_0)$ has one or zero solutions, $a\in(0,1)$, $x_0>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-distributions

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be integrable function such that

1. $f(x)\geq 0$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$
2. $f(x)=f(-x)$, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$
3. $f(x)$ is non-decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$

Let $a\in(0,1)$ and $x_0>0$. Can we prove that the equation
$$ f(x) = af(x-x_0) $$
has either one or zero solutions in the support of $f(x)$?

My attempt: Clearly, there cannot be a solution on $(-\infty,0)$, since we have the following inequality:
$$ x<0 \implies af(x-x_0) < f(x-x_0) \leq f(x) $$
follows since $f$ is non-decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$. This seems like very obvious... what am I missing? Here is an image where $f$ is the normal PDF:
[image]

Note that if $f(x)$ is the uniform PDF then it doesn't have any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a function equal $2$ on $[-1,1]$ and equal $1$ on $[-2,-1)\cup(1,2]$ (and zero otherwise). Then for $x_0=1$ and $a=1/2$ you get infinitely many solutions on the support. Your claim is false in this generality. I think it is true if you assume that your function is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Nice counterexample.... any idea how one might prove it for strictly increasing on $(-\infty,0)$?

Comment: The property is false even in that case. Take for example $f(x)=e^{-|x|}$. Then say $e^{-2}e^{-(x-2)}=e^{-x}$ and, consequently, $f(x)=e^{-2}f(x-2)$ for all $x>2$. In your case it works because your function decays too fast at infinity and the translation and shrinking effect are unbalanced.

Comment: Right. I think I need to make a statement like $f(x)=O(e^{-|x|^p})$ as $|x|\to\infty$ for some $p>1$. Thanks!

Comment: That should work. But, you see.. the question is actually more subtle than it appears.